# docker compose: ERROR: unable to select packages

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I followed this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

and got:

```
Step 5/10 : RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
 ---> Running in 534c2c19c358
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: temporary error (try again later)
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  gcc (no such package):
    required by: world[gcc]
  linux-headers (no such package):
    required by: world[linux-headers]
  musl-dev (no such package):
    required by: world[musl-dev]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers' returned a non-zero code: 3
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The example for the Dockerfile works for me. The warnings you get indicate that it might be a temporary problem. For how long have it failed for you? Are you behind a firewall or something else that might cause you to not be able to connect to the alpine package repositories?

Comment: I have the same problem on VirtualBox using alpine to install docker

Comment: Anyone solved this??

Answer (score 1):

I have just got the same error. For me, the problem was previous cached datas.
So,

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

solved this. I guess it was trying to build it by using cached image which actually doesn't exist.